# How do I find which client CMName is pending ack in TibRV?

Tags: tibco-rv

I have certified messaging enabled for TibcoRV and ledger file which is constantly growing causing my app to die eventually.

With full control of the box (access to TibRV web interface, ledger file itself) is it possible to determine what CMName used the client connected to our app which is not confirming the messages (i.e. we are waiting for ACK from)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways you can inspect a ledger file

- Use a Hawk method (for example via Hawk Display) called **reviewLedger**. This is available if your application is built using TIBCO BusinessWorks (or TIBCO adapters)
- Use the **ledgerpeek** command-line tool (staffware from TIBCO) to inspect the file

Comment: Answer I was hoping for ... :) Thx